# General transformation matrix

Tags: matrices, transformation

I am currently working through some of my maths assignment, and i have this question, and i can't work out what it means, and i am sure there is something to missing which would make this question make more sense, here is the question:

> What is the general transformation matrix for a rotation of angle $\theta$ about the origin?

That is all the questions says, any one able to help me out, who may understand it better then me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map which rotates any vector in the plane an angle $\theta$ around the origin is a linear map. Hence it can be given by multiplication by a matrix. What is this matrix?

Comment: there isn't one given, that was the whole question, thats why i don't know how to solve it

Comment: Well, you asked what the question means, not how to solve it. I answered that as best I could.

Comment: ah right, when you said What is this matrix is made me think you hadn't fully answered it, but your do summarize it better then i could. Thanks for the help.